# isql not displaying string data for some rows

Tags: sql-server, unix, isql

I am running into an issue regarding isql on Unix where I am running a simple "SELECT <string_field> from  where  = " from a table, but it returns a blank string despite data existing in the row. The string field in particular can have a lot of newline characters in it and contains spaces. Here's an example of what the string output would look like:

> Profile Update. Source: HCOM
> Leisure Country changed.  Before: GB. After: null
> Business Address Line 1 changed.  Before: null. After: 44 Placeholder RD
> Business Address Line 2 changed.  Before: null. After: UNIT 2
> Business City changed.  Before: null. After: Placeholder
> Business State changed.  Before: null. After: BH
> Business Postal Code changed.  Before: null. After: 9988
> Business Country changed.  Before: null. After: AU

Upon some digging it looks like there is a 300 character limit baked into isql that it seems like we are hitting with our data. Is there any way to override that limit? We tried using -mNUM but this did not work.

Comment: I think it is `isql -w 1000000 .....` (use whatever number you need). IMO, your question isn't super clear, so I may be misinterpreting your need. Hopefully `man isql` will show you all your possible options. Good luck.